# How do I create an array of hashes and loop through them in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to create an array of hashes, but I'm having trouble looping through the array. I have tried this code, but it does not work:

```
for  ($i = 0; $i<@pattern; $i++){
  while(($k, $v)= each $pattern[$i]){
    debug(" $k: $v");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, why aren't you `use`ing `strict` and `warnings`? The following lines should be at the top of every Perl program you create, right after `#!/usr/bin/perl`. *Always*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

And I know you aren't because I'm pretty sure you'd get some nice error messages out of `strict` and `warnings` from this, and from many other places in your code as well, judging by your variable use.

Second, why aren't you doing this:

```
for my $i (@pattern) {
  ..
}
```

That loops through every element in `@pattern`, assigning them to `$i` one at a time. Then, in your loop, when you want a particular element, just use `$i`. Changes to `$i` will be reflected in `@pattern`, and when the loop exits, `$i` will fall out of scope, essentially cleaning up after itself.

Third, for the love of Larry Wall, *please* declare your variables with `my` to localize them. It's really not that hard, and it makes you a better person, I promise.

Fourth, and last, your array stores *references* to hashes, not hashes. If they stored hashes, your code would be wrong because hashes start with `%`, not `$`. As it is, references (of any kind) are scalar values, and thus start with `$`. So we need to *dereference* them to get hashes:

```
for my $i (@pattern) {
  while(my($k, $v) = each %{$i}) {
    debug(" $k: $v");
  }
}
```

Or, your way:

```
for  (my $i = 0; $i<@pattern; $i++) { # added a my() for good measure
  while(my($k, $v) = each %{$pattern[$i]}) {
    debug(" $k: $v");
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha, thank you for your answer, even if there was a lot to read through to get there :p What I was looking for was the %{$i} (or %{$_} to regain some of my Perl honor).

Comment: For the record, the brackets aren't strictly necessary - you could write `%$i` in this case. The reason I used brackets is that, if you get more complex than just `$i`, you need them: `%{$pattern[$i]}` can't be written as `%$pattern[$i]`, because the second is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
for my $hashref (@pattern) {
    for my $key (keys %$hashref) {
        debug "$key: $hashref->{$key}";
    }
}
```

The biggest problem with what you were trying was `each $pattern[$i]`.  The [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) function expects a hash to work on, but `$pattern[$i]` returns a hashref (i.e. a reference to a hash).  You could fix your code by dereferencing `$pattern[$i]` as a hash:

```
while(my($k, $v) = each %{$pattern[$i]}) {
```

Also, beware of the each function, it can [leave the hash iterator in an incomplete state](http://svok.blogspot.com/2009/07/adventures-in-ignorance-each-keys-and.html).

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds. Perhaps I should ramble less.

Comment: I try to post quickly, then go back and ramble.

Comment: It is a good strategy. Truly I have much to learn. Also, interesting piece about why `each()` is bad. I like your Star Wars reference.

Comment: The `each` function isn't so much bad as dangerous.  And the `keys` function isn't completely safe either: `my @keys = keys %hash`.  What happens if %hash is a tied dbm that holds many times what memory will hold?  In this case, `while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) {}` is clearly superior.

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation for the perl data structures cookbook:
[`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)